# Cannot get response when using socket in C++.NET

Tags: c++, .net, sockets, c++-cli

I wrote two programs, one as server and another as client. The server is written in standard C++ using `WinSock2.h`. It is a simple *echo* server which means the server responds what it receives back to the client. I used a new thread for every client's connection, and in each thread:

```cpp
Socket* s = (Socket*) a;

while (1) {
  std::string r = s->ReceiveLine()
  if (r.empty()) {
    break;
  }
  s->SendLine(r);
}

delete s;
return 0;
```

`Socket` is a class from [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/sockets.html). The server runs properly and I've tested it using `telnet`, it works well.

Then I wrote the client using C++.NET (or C++/CLI), `TcpClient` is used to send and receive message from the server. The code is like:

```cpp
String^ request = "test";
TcpClient ^ client = gcnew TcpClient(server, port);

array<Byte> ^ data = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(request);

NetworkStream ^ stream = client->GetStream();
stream->Write(data, 0, data->Length);

data = gcnew array<Byte>(256);
String ^ response = String::Empty;
int bytes = stream->Read(data, 0, data->Length);
response = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(data, 0, bytes);

client->Close();
```

When I run the client and tries to show the response message onto my form, the program halted at the line `int bytes = stream->Read(data, 0, data->Length);` and cannot fetch the response. The server is running and there's nothing to do with the network as they are all running on the same computer.

I guess the reason is that the data server responds with is less than `data->Length`, so the `Read` method is waiting for more data. Is that right? How should I solve this problem?

## Edit

I think I've solved the problem... There are another two methods in the `Socket` class, `ReceiveBytes` and `SendBytes`, and these two methods will not delete the unused space in the bytes array. So the length of data back from the server will match that from the client, thus the `Read` method will not wait for more data to come.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string Socket::ReceiveLine() {
std::string ret;
while (1) {
char r;

switch(recv(s_, &r, 1, 0)) {
  case 0: // not connected anymore;
          // ... but last line sent
          // might not end in \n,
          // so return ret anyway.
    return ret;
  case -1:
    return "";
//      if (errno == EAGAIN) {
//        return ret;
//      } else {
//      // not connected anymore
//      return "";
//      }
}

    ret += r;
    if (r == '\n')  return ret;
  }
}
```

i guess receiveline function of the server is waiting for an enter key '\n'.

just try with "test\n" string.

```
String^ request = "test\n";
// other codes....
```

Comment: Thanks. I used another functions `ReceiveBytes` and `SendBytes` and it works.